# What does match_incoming_request_route option in gRPC transcoding do?

Tags: grpc, envoyproxy

I'm trying to figure out what `match_incoming_request_route` option in envoy does. If I read this doc correctly it suggests using it to match on custom route path (the `google.api.http` annotation). But the custom route works just fine when `match_incoming_request_route` is set to `false`. Furthermore we tried reading the code and find out the flag is only used in [here](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/06505f2424ad3f894af404a07bcfd7582aa8f3b9/source/extensions/filters/http/grpc_json_transcoder/json_transcoder_filter.cc#L503..L505).

Answer (score 0):

Found [the PR](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/pull/2848) and [related issue](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/2847), which explains the usecase. closing this.